# Show variable between single quotes?

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a sourcefile (config) with:

```
TEST=master.url.com
```

I have a bash script which is written like this. I ssh to a server and I try to login on my cluster. I have to perform `login -s masterurl` as command:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i mykey.pem centos@ec2-xx-xx 'login -s ${TEST}'
```

Now I try to use the ${TEST} between the single quotes. It has to show master.url.com but I don't get this working. Someone who can help me?

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: thanks @hejip06, I tried a lot but always with my single quotes on the outside. Sorry

Comment: This is, effectively, a duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/258523) which is linked from the bash info page.